# How to design memberNumbers table SQL

Tags: sql

I'm struggling to implement table that will hold information about
number of:
childrens - male and female,
adults    - male and female,
elders    - male and female

I have created table stateMembers like this:

```
    +-----------------------------------------------------+
    | id | stateId | gender  | children | adults | elders |
    +----+---------+---------+----------+--------+--------+
    | 1  | 4       | male    | 2000     | 590    |  900   |    
    | 2  | 4       | female  | 2000     | 590    |  900   |    
    | 3  | 3       | male    | 500      | 700    |  1900  |    
    | 4  | 3       | female  | 200      | 159    |  100   |    
    +----+---------+---------+----------+--------+--------+
```

How can I redesign it to make easy organization of result when other record added for each State.
Inorder to get the total of children male and female, adults male and female.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would organize it as

| id | stateId | gender | age_category | nmbr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | male | children | 2000 |
| 2 | 4 | male | adults | 590 |
| 3 | 4 | male | elders | 900 |
| 4 | 4 | female | children | 2000 |

...

Allowing any grouping you need further on.

Comment: Thanks Serg, But what if New data is added or in case of editing data, if will force to edit each age_category separately if I use more rows for male and female. I have tried this approach but I get difficulties representing data to view html table. Is it possible to use one row for each stateId and adding created_date column  if new record of same stateId added?

Comment: @OneBuyu Yes it is possible to query the  DB to return the  view as your original one. It's known as pivot

Comment: I will try even I know in Mysql pivot is not supported. but what Happen If I add colums like this: adult_male, adult_female, children_male, children_female, elder_male, elder_female, Is it bad Idea if I did that?

Comment: When DBMS has no a pivot clause, pivot is generated by conditional aggregation, a lot of examples over here. The recommended design is simple and all possible aggregations can be derived easily from the table like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question very well but I think this would be a better construction for the table

```
+----------------------------------+
| id | stateId | male     | female |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
| 1  | children| 2000     | 590    |     
| 2  | adult   | 2000     | 590    |     
| 3  | elders  | 500      | 700    |         
+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: The stateId is the foreign key of the Satate table, The issue I'im trying to solve is to store number of members and their gender and the member type if member are children, adult or elder. At the final output to get children male and children and their total. But the table I have designed it gives me difficult if for the next time/year a new record need to be added.

Comment: As Serg did by adding  age_category, but I think it will produce more rows for stateId for each age_category which will force hard work to edit information for each stateMembers id